# Download all files in a URL

Tags: c++

I am currently developing a feature in a Game in **C++**.
I provide an URL (eg:"https://ServerName/../FolderName/").
There are few files in this folder: .png, .txt, etc.
I need to download all these files into a specific location (For the Game to fetch them from that location)
I am able to download single file by providing the complete URL.
Any idea on how to download all files in a single HTTP request??
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Any idea on how to download all files in a single HTTP request??` You can't, unless the server provides them as one file (i.e. an archive like tar or zip).

Comment: HTTP has no concept of folders and files. It only knows URLs. These are not interchangeable. In particular, since there’s no “folder” URL you can’t iterate over the items inside a URL.

Comment: Use FTP instead - if that is an option.

Comment: @tkausl - Ok, I will try zipping the contents and download them, unzip to the required location. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP request is asking for a single resource from the server via a unique URI. What you're asking for is to be able to ask for multiple resources from the server with a single URI, which means you don't understand how HTTP works. So the answer to your question is NO, and it's impossible.

Comment: If the server tells you which files are in the folder, then you can.

Comment: @user253751, how? If each file has a unique URI and you can't refer to multiple files with a single URI/URL.

Comment: you can get the URL for each file, then download it

Comment: That wont be 1 single request bro.